# Is it possible to use SQLAlchemy create_engine and pass a certificate from an environment variable?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

The title pretty much sums it up. I can connect using `sslrootcert` as an argument to `create_engine`, assuming that it points to an existing certificate in my local storage. However, I would like to pass the certificate using an environment variable, or load it from a vault, etc..

Is this possible? I haven't found any documentation or example unfortunately.

If this is not possible, can someone explain why?

If this is a dumb question, can someone explain why?

EDIT:
I want to be able to load the certificate as a string from an environment variable. I want to pass my certificate as a string to the `create_engine` function. I do not wish to load an env var string that would point to a file in the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you're trying to do (in this case, the SSL variables, if available, are fed into this method earlier)?

```
global qry_engine, meta, tbl_application, tbl_application_table
ssl_args = {}
if ssl_server_cert_path is not None:
    ssl_args['ca'] = ssl_server_cert_path
if ssl_client_cert_path is not None:
    ssl_args['cert'] = ssl_client_cert_path
if ssl_key_cert_path is not None:
    ssl_args['key'] = ssl_key_cert_path
if ssl_args != {}:
    ssl_args['check_hostname'] = False
    ssl_args = {'ssl': ssl_args}

try:
    # Adding support for local_infile flag, so we can use the LOAD DATA command to load from files
    connect_args = ssl_args
    connect_args['local_infile'] = True
    qry_engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://' + db_uid + ':' + db_pw + '@' + db_addr, connect_args=connect_args,                                   
    pool_recycle=3600, echo=False, future=True)
```

You can feed in whatever you want for the ssl_args, grabbing them from an environment variable or anywhere else you'd like.

Comment: No, unfortunately not, I want to load the certificate as an env var, not load the path to the file

Comment: OK, I'm a bit out of my league now but can you use an SSL thumbprint or is the entire SSL string required? If a thumbprint will suffice, does this link help you build the connect string? https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/#:~:text=SSL%20with%20a%20thumbprint%20specific%20personal%20store%2Dbased%20certificate